# How do you test a function that has a lot of 'this' inside?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, tdd

How do I test this function that has no return to validate, I am testing a file with a lot of methods that only change mostly flags like the following.

```
customerDidProvideCellPhoneNumber() {
    this.screenElements.inputPhoneNumber.writable = true;
    this.screenElements.checkDidNotProvideEmail.writable = true;
    this.formGroup.get('phoneNumber').enable({ onlySelf: true });
    this.screenElements.btnSendSMS.enabled = true;
    this.screenElements.alertCellPhone.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Your test should validate that the function does what you expect it to, and there are ways other than simply inspecting the return value.  In this case, I assume that the function is expected to set the state of several other objects in the system.  So your test can (a) create/initialize these other objects. You can mock them if necessary, (b) call this method, (c) inspect these other objects to validate that their state has changed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going for a unit test (as opposed to a larger scoped behavioral test), you should consider using a mock `this` and asserting its properties were set as expected.

```js
function customerDidProvideCellPhoneNumber() {
    this.screenElements.inputPhoneNumber.writable = true;
}

let mockThis = { screenElements: { inputPhoneNumber: {} } };
customerDidProvideCellPhoneNumber.call(mockThis);
console.assert(mockThis.screenElements.inputPhoneNumber.writable === true);
```